# jquery serialize sortable and input form

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have code like this one.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <ul class="sortable" id="sortable_list">
        <li id="1">whatever</li>
        <li id="2">you</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenval" value="111">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenval" value="222">
</form>
```

I want to join or get the values of sortable and input fields.

jQuery:

```
$('input#hiddenval').each(function() {
    cols.push($(this).val());                                       
});         


$('ul.sortable-list').each(function() {
    columns.push($(this).sortable('serialize'));
});
```

I'd like to see output like this (when submit the form):

```
sortable_list[0]=1&sortable_list[1]=2&hiddenval[0]=111&hiddenval[1]=222
```

Comment: id be unique (hiddenval)

Comment: what is `id` in `$(id +..` ?

Comment: sorry i forgot its not included.. $(id +..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VT974/)

```
$('li').each(function(index){
columns.push($(this).attr('id'));
result=result+'sortable_list['+index+']='+$(this).attr('id')+'&';
});   
$( 'input.hiddenval').each(function(index){
cols.push($(this).val());
 if (index === total - 1) {
 result=result+'hiddenval['+index+']='+$(this).val();
}
else
{
result=result+'hiddenval['+index+']='+$(this).val()+'&';
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no great way to get the indexes in there using the default methods, so you'll have to be a little creative.

### HTML

```
<form>
    <ul class="ui-sortable" id="sortable_list">
        <li id="1">whatever</li>
        <li id="2">me</li>
        <li id="3">you</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenval1" value="111">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenval2" value="222">
    <button class="serialize">Serialize</button>
</form>
```

I changed the input field `id` to `name` and made them unique.  You should never have id's of the same value, and using `name` makes allows you to use the pre-built jQuery serialize() method.

### jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortable_list").sortable();

        $('button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // made this into an Array for easy looping
            var arraySerialized = $("#sortable_list").sortable("toArray");
            // build the string as we loop
            var listSerialized = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arraySerialized.length; i++) {
                listSerialized += 'sortable_list[' + i + ']=' + arraySerialized[i] + '&';
            }

            // to make life easy!
            var formSerialized = $('form').serialize();

            // concatenate the two and return it
            return listSerialized + formSerialized;
        });

    });
```

After shuffling around the sortable li's, I got `sortable_list[0]=3&sortable_list[1]=1&sortable_list[2]=2&hiddenval1=111&hiddenval2=222`

[JSFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/724RE/)

Hope this helped!